# python tic tac toe winning conditons

Tags: python

I am coding the logic for a tic tac toe game.

I have already checked for all the winning conditions for tic tac toe.

I now need to check if the game is a draw.

```
board_values = [[x, x, x],
                [None, None, None],
                [None, None, None]]
#the if statement for that winning condition would be
if board_values[0][0]=='x' and board_values[1][0] =='x' and board_values[2][0]=='x':
    board.display_message('player x won')
```

How would I write an `if` statement to determine a draw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do that indirectly.  If the board is full, and *neither* player has a win, then it's a draw.  It would be the **else** clause of your if-elif-else statement.

```
if board_values[0][0] == 'x' and \
   board_values[1][0] == 'x' and \
   board_values[2][0] == 'x':

    board.display_message('player x won')

elif board_values[0][0] == 'o' and \
     board_values[1][0] == 'o' and \
     board_values[2][0] == 'o':

    board.display_message('player o won')

else:
    board.display_message('The game is a draw')
```

Of course, you have to extend the checks for all possible wins.

---

Speaking of which, there's a neat way to encode the spaces to aid in checking.  Instead of using the canonical

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Number the squares as a 3x3 magic square

```
6 7 2
1 5 9
8 3 4
```

Now you can check for a win somewhat more efficiently: if a player owns any three squares that add up to 15, that's a win.  Use **itertools** to generate those sets of 3, wrap that in a **map(sum())**, and slap an **if any()** check on that: your check for a win reduces to one complex line of code.

Comment: I am gonna try that out.

Comment: TIL how to solve this with your magic square technique!  Wicked.