# How do a check if a column or row in a nested list has the same string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I need to check if a nested list has a column with the same string

```
grid = [
  ["x", " ", "x"],
  ["x", " ", " "],
  ["x", "x", "x"]
]
#if grid has a column or row with the same string (such as the first column and last row) then it will say "yes"
```

I've only managed to do it for rows:

```
grid = [
  ["x", " ", "x"],
  ["x", " ", " "],
  ["x", " ", "x"]
]
print(grid)


row = ['x', 'x', 'x']


if row in grid:
  print("Yes")
else:
  print("no")
```

Comment: I would suggest posting an example along with what you have tried so far

Comment: just edited the post to show what i have done so far (it only works for rows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python tic tac toe winning conditons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559066/python-tic-tac-toe-winning-conditons)

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to do what you need is to transpose your main grid to check for columns as follows:

```
gridTranspose = list(zip(*grid))
```

This will basically reverse rows and columsn in your grid.

Next, save your column as a row (e.g.)

if your grid is:

[
1
1
0
]

just make the variable the same way (column = [1, 1, 0])

then it should work!

Comment: not gonna lie im still a bit confused. i know what this does (because you explained it) but i don't know how to implement this into my code

Comment: Give me some time and I will try to give you an example

Answer (score 0):

`-1` means not same

```py
grid = [
  ["x", " ", "x"],
  ["x", " ", " "],
  ["x", "x", "x"]
]

row_same = [index if all(map(lambda x: x==i[0], i)) else -1 for index, i in enumerate(grid)] 
#[-1, -1, 2]
column_same = [j if all(map(lambda x: x==grid[0][j], [i[j] for i in grid])) else -1 for j in range(len(grid[0]))] 
#[0, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an easy and understandable solution.

So, the basic idea is to take the list of rows and make a new list of columns and then check between them -

```
num = range(len(grid)) # Just an extra var, so that it is readable

lst_of_columns = [[grid[j][i] for j in num] for i in num]
# This makes a list of columns. Take it slow, print it and understand the logic

for i in num: # These lines check if rows and columns are same
    for j in num:
        if grid[i] == lst_of_columns[j]: # grid[i] = row 1,2,3...
            print('yes')                 # lst_of_columns[j] = columns 1,2,3

        else:
            print('no')
```

I hope you understand the logic behind this.
Also, this will work for any number of rows and columns